# Create new native php project in homestead box

Tags: laravel, homestead

I want to create new project (not a laravel project) in homestead box. I have edited homestead.yaml but when i access on the web browser, it is always routed to the laravel project instead of the map i 've added to homestead.yaml. Here is the conf :

```
    ---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
mariadb: true

authorize: c:/Users/Fauzan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - c:/Users/Fauzan/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: d:/Projects/Homestead
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
    - map: belajarphp.lol
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Belajarphp/

databases:
    - homestead
    - belajarphp
```

I go to 192.168.10.10/belajarphp still directed to the laravel project.
I have added "192.168.10.10 belajarphp.lol" and opened in web browser still directed to laravel project.

I don't have any idea

---

solved this by destroy vagrant and rebuilt from stractch

Comment: Have you run `vagrant provision`? And you should add the belajarphp.lol to your `hosts` file to make sure you can access that url directly.

Comment: i 've run vagrant reload --provision and still the same. finally i destroy the vagrant and rebuilt it from stracth and worked. thanks